# google colabにBox2Dインストールする方法

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

colab上でOpenAIGymのBipedalWalker-v2を実行するために，colabにBox2Dをインストールしようとしています．
そこで，以下のコマンドでインストールしようとしました．

```
!apt-get install python-box2d > /dev/null
!pip install gym[Box_2D]
import gym
env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v2")
```

しかし，以下のimportされていないと表示されてしまいました．

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gym/envs/box2d/lunar_lander.py in <module>()
2 import numpy as np
3 
----> 4 import Box2D
5 from Box2D.b2 import (edgeShape, circleShape, fixtureDef, 
polygonShape, revoluteJointDef, contactListener)
6 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Box2D'
```

apt-getを使わずにgithubから自分でビルドしようとしましたが，以下のようにパスが違うと言われてしまいました．

```
fatal: destination path 'pybox2d' already exists and is not an 
empty directory.
Using setuptools (version 39.1.0).
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pybox2d/setup.py", line 151, in <module>
write_init()
File "pybox2d/setup.py", line 66, in write_init
license_header = open(os.path.join(source_dir, 
'pybox2d_license_header.txt')).read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'Box2D/pybox2d_license_header.txt'
```

どのようにしたらcolab上でBox2Dをインストールできるでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のコマンドで取り敢えずenvまでは動作します。

```
!pip install box2d-py
!pip install gym[Box_2D]
import gym
env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v2")
```